# How to render string literal with html tags in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've wrote a custom view to parse markdown files using regex and
I'm passing content as a string literal to the template

```
context = "Django is a web framework written using <a href='https://www.python.org/'>Python</a>"

return render(request, "blog/post.html", {"context": context})
```

And in template:

```
<p>{{ context }}</p>
```

But the engine renders content as a plain text. How to make links to be links and paragraphs to be paragraphs?

Comment: You need to mark it as safe because you trust the markup in it; `{{ context|safe }}`. Alternatively you can use `mark_safe()` in the view to pass a safe string in the context; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I have several other variables that work without safe filter. Why do these variables work without being marked as safe?

Comment: I'd assume the other variables don't contain anything that django considers potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `safe` template tag like @markwalker_ said in comments it will turn off autoescape of html tags.

```
 <p>{{ context|safe }}</p>
```